# p:schedule not rendering when its slotLabelFormat attribute is specified

Tags: jsf, primefaces, fullcalendar

According to [PrimeFaces 13 documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/13_0_0/#/components/schedule?id=schedule), the `slotLabelFormat` attribute of the `p:schedule` component is a string that determines the text to be displayed within a time slot and I understand that its value must be specified according to the referenced [momentjs documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/). I have tried several of those formats. Regardless of the specified format, the `p:schedule` component is not rendered. **Even [PrimeFaces showcase example](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule/configuration.xhtml?jfwid=8b063) fails** to render the `p:schedule` when `slotLabelFormat` is specified. Has anyone found a solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you use the right format such as ..

```xml
slotLabelFormat="['HH:mm']"
```

So in that PrimeFaces showcase enter `['HH:mm']` in that box and you will see it works.

On mine instead of `5pm` it shows `05:00` now.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing the brackets and single quotes. I added them and now it works. BTW, I don't see any mention of square brackets and quotes in the PrimeFaces documentation; and in Moment.js I only see that square brackets must be used to escape characters. Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Its because this is a passthrough to FullSchedule so its really whatever the FullSchedule docs say.

Comment: Do you mean FullCalendar (https://fullcalendar.io) ?

Comment: Yes PrimeFaces just wraps FullCalendar.io version 5